# I have an Oracle stored procedure with one IN argument and one OUT argument . I need to call it from PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Oracle stored procedure :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spu_edt_object3(
o_in VARCHAR,
o_id_object OUT VARCHAR
) as
begin
o_id_object := 'Hello World';
end;
```

Powerbuilder code:

```
string o_message, param, st,o_id_object
o_message= 'HIiiiiii'
DECLARE proc_update PROCEDURE FOR  spu_edt_object3
@a_in => :o_message,
@a_id_object = :o_id_object OUTPUT

USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE proc_update;

if SQLCA.SqlCode <> 0 then
     MessageBox("SQL error " + String(SQLCA.SQLDBCode),   SQLCA.SQLErrText )
RETURN -1
end if

FETCH proc_update INTO :o_id_object;

if SQLCA.SqlCode <> 0 then
     MessageBox("SQL error " + String(SQLCA.SQLDBCode),   SQLCA.SQLErrText )
RETURN -1
end if
```

I get this error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SPU_EDT_OBJECT3'
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Have you tried naming the parameters in PB the same as they are in the stored proc? (i.e., 'o_in' and not 'a_in')

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it as local external function on you transaction object like this:

```
subroutine spu_edt_object3 (string a_in, ref long a_id_object) rpcfunc alias for "spu_edt_object3"
```

Note the "ref" keyword in the declaration indicating that this is a reference type of variable.

Then you will be able to call it like this:

```
long  ll_Out // I have assumed that this is a number
string ls_In

SQLCA.spu_edt_object3(ls_In, ll_Out)
```